# Can apex invoke methods dynamically

Tags: apex

I am trying to invoke methods dynamically in Apex. Something I want to achieve looks like below:

```
if (methodName == 'FuncA') {
   FuncA();
}
if(methodName == 'FuncB') {
   FuncB();
}
```

I want to be able to invoke that dynamically. I checked this with ChatGPT. The 3.5 model suggests this:

```
String methodName = 'FuncA';
Type t = Type.forName('MyClass');
Object obj = t.newInstance();
obj.invoke(methodName, null);
```

This looks awesome, but unfortunately this doesn't work. GPT-4 model suggests me using a strategy pattern. which will definitely work, but seems to be an overkill to me. The code looks like below:

```
public interface Strategy {
    void execute();
}

public class FuncA implements Strategy {
    public void execute() {
        // implementation of FuncA
    }
}

public class FuncB implements Strategy {
    public void execute() {
        // implementation of FuncB
    }
}
```

Is there something simpler to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apex does not have dynamic method dispatch.

There are a variety of ways to *simulate* dynamic dispatch, or achieve its goals in different ways.

Something like the strategy pattern in your question is one option. There, you move the dynamism to the class level, which Apex does support via `Type.forName()` and interface-typed values.

Another approximation is implementing the `Callable` interface to define a completely generic entry point - but the content of that entry point is going to be a chain of `if` statements or a `switch` construct, statically dispatching calls based on parameter values.

There are others too, of course. But fundamentally, Apex doesn’t have true dynamic dispatch.

Comment: There is the use of anonymous apex through the tooling API, but to extract any return value would be highly challenging. Plus this would be unlikely to be of real use due to poor performance and security concerns. I more mention it to rule it out.